How can I know through cisco netbox api if a device is newly added to cisco Netbox
I am trying to find about how can I fetch information about devices that newly added to the netbox through rest api or python-netbox sdk. In documentation a method is there to list all devices but I want to List devices only new to netbox. Please provide help would appreciate greatly.
I tried using python-netbox sdk and netbox rest api but I can only list all devices in the system.
